# Is it possible to create a parameter binding on both FromURI and FromBody?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I looked up up the documentation for ASP.NET Web API parameter binding, they seem to have either fromURI and fromBody only. Is it possible to do both?

Here is some background info. I'm creating a webhook receiver/handler, where I have control over which URL is the webhook, but I do not have control over what the payload will be like until later stage of the workflow, so I need to take it in as JSON string first.

My hope is to be able to set up the route that can take in querystring and also Json string payload from HTTP POST. For example .../api/incoming?source=A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to use both the Post data from the body and some parameters from the URI. The example below should capture your "source=a" value from the queryString.

```
    [Route("incoming")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] string data, string source)
    {
        //Do something

        return Ok("my return value");
    }
```

Or you could use as below if you formatted your route as .../api/incoming/source/A.

```
    [Route("incoming/{source:string}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] string data, string source)
    {
        //Do something

        return Ok("my return value");
    }
```

Comment: Using a string parameter type will most likely not do what you hope.  See this post http://www.bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api

Comment: @DarrelMiller I agree.  We usually map an object model to the JSON that comes into our API's.  Or use Dictionary<string, string> or others depending upon the data coming in.  He asked specifically about JSON as a string so I didn't elaborate.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the inputs. Since currently I am blackboxed on what the content of JSON string will be, so I can't create object model to map to it at the parameter binding stage. Since I cannot do [FromBody] string data, would [FromBody] JToken data work in this case?